# IntelliJ warning for type assertion on generic embedded interfaces

Tags: go, generics, intellij-idea, goland

Say I have some generic interface type, along with another generic interface type that embeds the former:

```go
type Mapper[T any] interface {
    Map(T) T
}

type FilteredMapper[T any] interface {
    Mapper[T]

    Filter(T) bool
}
```

Now, we have some (generic) type that uses a `Mapper[T]`, and if the contained mapper happens to be a `FilteredMapper[T]`, it wants to call its `Filter` function first. Or, for here, we just do the type assertion:

```go
type Processor[T any] struct {
    mapper Mapper[T]
}

func (p *Processor[T]) Process() {
    if _, ok := p.mapper.(FilteredMapper[T]); ok {
        fmt.Println("ok")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not ok")
    }
}
```

If I use this (see [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/c6rxJlToBQ4)), everything works fine. However, IntelliJ highlights the type assertion with a warning that reads

> Impossible interface assertion from 'interface {...}' to 'FilteredMapper[T]'. Ambiguous: 'Map'

I don't understand why this would be ambiguous. Is it a false-positive? Am I missing something here, and more importantly, doing something wrong?

Just for completeness sake, the following does "fix" the warning:

```
-   if _, ok := p.mapper.(FilteredMapper[T]); ok {
+   if _, ok := any(p.mapper).(FilteredMapper[T]); ok {
```

Comment: *"Am I ... doing something wrong?"* -- If the code compiles with the standard `go build` tool then the answer is _No_. Instead it is the non-standard tool (the IDE) that is complaining that is wrong. It could be misconfigured, or out of date, or simply behind in terms of supporting the language's latest features.

Comment: To me it looks like a false-positive, can you please fill out a bug request on YouTrack? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/GO